# Why should I use classes in python?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am a  very amateur learner of Python, and I have recently started learning the concept of classes. I can understand the concept of classes (very) roughly, but I can't understand why I can't simply write some functions instead of writing a class?

For example, (I am learning from [Interactive python](http://www.interactivepython.com)) one of the exercise given (which I am supposed to write using a class) is :

1. Add a `distanceFromPoint` method that works similar to `distanceFromOrigin` except that it takes a `Point` as a parameter and computes the distance between that point and self.
2. Add a method `reflect_x` to `Point` which returns a new `Point`, one which is the reflection of the point about the x-axis. For example, `Point(3, 5).reflect_x()` is `(3, -5)`.

They written the code using classes like this:

```
import math

class Point:
    """ Point class for representing and manipulating x,y coordinates. """

def __init__(self, initX, initY):
    """ Create a new point at the given coordinates. """
    self.x = initX
    self.y = initY

def getX(self):
    return self.x

def getY(self):
    return self.y

def distanceFromOrigin(self):
    return ((self.x ** 2) + (self.y ** 2)) ** 0.5

def distanceFromPoint(self, otherP):
    dx = (otherP.getX() - self.x)
    dy = (otherP.getY() - self.y)
    return math.sqrt(dy**2 + dx**2)

p = Point(3, 3)
q = Point(6, 7)

print(p.distanceFromPoint(q))
```

Why should I use class when I can write them simply like this:

```
def distanceFromPoint(p,q): # they are tuples
    y = (p[0]-q[0])**(2)+(p[1]-q[1])**(2)
    return y**(1/2)

def reflectx(p):
    return (p[0],-p[1])

p = (3,3)
q = (6,7)
```

Comment: At least the `getX` and `getY` methods are not considered _pythonic code_. You can access the `x` and `y` attributes directly.

Comment: Apart from more general answers below: you don't really need the getX/getY. Python has no real private members, so using just x/y is ok. If you need to override them, properties are always available.

Comment: @Matthias: I am new to python. I can't understand what is pythonic code and why getX, getY are not pythonic codes ?

Comment: You don't need to lose sleep over what is or isn't 'Pythonic', but I hope you see that `mypoint.x` is simpler and clearer than `mypoint.getX()`. It's hard to illustrate the power of OOP in such a simple example though. I never really 'got it' until I had a real problem to solve, which I suddenly realised was amazingly straightforward if I wrote a class that inherited from someone else's previously defined class.

Comment: @nekomatic: Can you please mention one of those exercise in python OOP which led you to the "aha" moment ?

Comment: As I said it was a real problem, not an exercise - like you, I hadn't previously seen the point of OOP based on the artificial examples I had encountered. Maybe you can think of something you actually want to create, and use that process as a vehicle to learn some of these techniques?

Comment: Though it seems that your question is 'Why OO', I really feel the overuse of OO approach in python at least. I've seen so much of code doing simple things, using OO for no (at least obvious) reasons (no inheritance used at all etc). The whole code could be much simpler without writing classes, and much easily testable with functional programming approach. That doesn't mean classes are bad thing, they are necessary to solve most of big and/or complex problems, but I've always found them being overused.

Answer (score 22):

One of the big advantages of using OOP is **extensibility**.

Let's say you'd written an application that processes lots of data in the form of points. Now your customer adds to the specification that as well as the x and y coordinate of each point, your app needs to know what colour each point is.

If you'd written your code to store each point as a tuple, `(x, y)`, you might add the colour as a third value: `(x, y, colour)`. But now you have to go through all of your code to find the places where it's broken because you changed the data format. If you'd used a class, you could simply define a new class that inherits from `Point` and adds the necessary capabilities:

```
class ColouredPoint(Point):
    """ Class for points which are coloured, based on Point """

    def __init__(self, initX, initY, initCol):
        Point.__init__(self, initX, initY)
        self.colour = initCol

p = ColouredPoint(3, 3, "green")
q = ColouredPoint(6, 7, "red")
r = Point(8, 4)

print(p.distanceFromPoint(q))
print(p.colour)
print(p.distanceFromPoint(r))
```

All your code that worked with the `Point` class will still work with the new class, and you can do this even if you didn't write, or can't change, the definition of the `Point` class.

Comment: What do you mean by the broken code ? Can't a class-less function neglect the additional values ? For example, while coding without class, I may have a string on p[2] as a tuple, and tuple will neglect that while calculating the distance.

Comment: That's true, but what about your `reflectx` function in the question - it would lose the extra data. You can come up with a solution to that I'm sure, but I hope you see that the more possible changes and extensions to the original you think of, the harder it becomes to devise a data type that will always behave correctly. When you get to the complexity of real-world applications OOP is far easier and more robust, and the above is only one of the reasons for using OOP.

Comment: Am I missing something if I summarize the need for class as to "Add new functions ( to manipulate some objects ) or change the structure of the object, efficiently" ? What are the others reasons for using OOP ?

Comment: Apart from extensibility OOP has a lots of features like 1. Organization:- describing and defining both data and procedure in code. 2. State: - OOP helps you define and keep track of state. 3. Encapsulation: procedure and data are stored together. 4.Inheritance: Inheritance allows you to define data and procedure in one place (in one class), and then override or extend that functionality later. 5. Reusability: All of these reasons and others allow for greater reusability of code. Object oriented code allows you to write solid (tested) code once, and then reuse over and over.

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a function outside of a class.
But storing them in class is a better pratice in general in programming. OOP is considered to be more readable and also reusable.

And in this case, the distance between two **points** depends on points, so it's logical to have the **distanceFromPoint** method in this class.

Class also allow you to be sure than you calculate the distance from **Points** and not for tuples who can contains bad values, like more than two coordinates.

Comment: I may define a check (with if function) inside my distance function that if the first two data (in the tuple) are integer, then calculate, otherwise show an error. So why should I use class then ?

Answer (score 1):

Your example of a point is a bad one for justifying the use of classes.

A class is a great way of describing *what something is* rather than manipulating data. So a point just has two bits of information describing it (in 2D space anyway).

Think of something more abstract, like, a movie file. Movies have all sorts of information associated with them: title, duration, genres, actors, age rating, popularity, language, awards... goes on. Try writing functions that handle a long list of all of this information and you will quickly see the merits of a class.

Maths is maybe the one area where there really isn't that much contextual information, there are only a few variables and they define everything. Real-world data is less clearly defined and so benefits from the extensibility of classes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your second para (A class is a great ... ) ?  I can't understand that clearly without much examples and I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

[Functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) and [object-oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) programming are different paradigms.

In Python, everything is an object, even `int`s. The whole language goes towards object-oriented programming, which is why you should prefer going for it, especially if your program will grow.

Comment: You are mixing up **Functional programming** and **Imperative programming**.
Functional programming does not mean you use functions.
You can do **functionnal programming** in Python, but the way he described in the post was **imperative programming**